# transforming / combining variables (maps) into locals in terraform

Tags: terraform

In order to simplify variable definition, I'm grouping subnets and attributes (like security groups) into a list of dictionaries... which then has a layer of dicts etc.. (or maps/objects)

Here is a sample definition JSON:

```
"subnets": [
{
  "name": "inside",
  "prefix": "10.248.0.0/28",
  "route_table": true,
  "nsg": true,
  "security_group_rules": [
    {
      "name": "AllowAllInbound",
      "properties": {
        "priority": 100,
        "access": "Allow",
        "direction": "Inbound",
        "protocol": "*",
        "sourcePortRange": "*",
        "destinationPortRange": "*",
        "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
        "destinationAddressPrefix": "*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

With this single block, I'd like to be able to run through a loop to build out the subnets, then with a different resource block, build out the security groups. I'm having all sorts of issues being able to iterate over this.

I figured I should do something with locals so I can pull out what I need for each operation

on the subnet side:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each = var.subnets
  name                 = each.value.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.hub_network_rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.hub_vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = [each.value.prefix] 
}
```

Doesn't work due to issues with variable types: I'm defining the 'subnets' variable as:

```
variable "subnets" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    prefix = string
    route_table = bool
    nsg = bool
    security_group_rules = map(list(string))
  }))
}
```

I know TF is loosely typed, but it doesn't want to iterate over the objects since it is encountering other things.

Options:
1.break this out into separate elements - I'll run into this again, just on a smaller scale.
2. Find a way to create s local.subnets map and a local.security_groups map that references the var.subnets I have.

Looking for help on #2.

something like:

```
locals {
  subnets = for k,v in var.subnets: [
    {
      name = var.subnet.name
      prefix = var.subnet.prefix
    }
```

I'm WAY off here, but I think that gets across the issue. My brain goes to Python and list/dict comprehension but I can figure out how to do this with TF. I feel it is right in front of me, I just can't piece together the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform `for_each` accepts only set of strings or map of strings. Passing a `var` of something like a list simply wont work. What I suggest doing is the following:

```
# Create a JSON like variable for your subnets. Notice, this variable is a list, the type of it is inferred, we don't need to complicate ourselves here
variable "subnets" {
  default = [{
    "name" : "inside",
    "prefix" : "10.248.0.0/28",
    "route_table" : true,
    "nsg" : true,
    "security_group_rules" : [
      {
        "name" : "AllowAllInbound",
        "properties" : {
          "priority" : 100,
          "access" : "Allow",
          "direction" : "Inbound",
          "protocol" : "*",
          "sourcePortRange" : "*",
          "destinationPortRange" : "*",
          "sourceAddressPrefix" : "*",
          "destinationAddressPrefix" : "*"
        }
      }
    ]
  }]
}

# Create a local which maps the name of the the subnet to the subnet itself
locals {
  subnet_map =  { for s in var.subnets: s.name => s }
}

# Create the resources
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each             = toset([
                             for s in var.subnets: s.name
                         ]) # Note, we create a set from the subnet names. We can use these names to read out properties from the map created above
  name                 = each.value.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.hub_network_rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.hub_vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = [local.subnet_map[each.value].prefix] # We use the subnet names here
}
```

Update:

The reason why we need `subnet_map` is to have to following mapping:

```
subnet_map = {
  "inside" = {
    "name" = "inside"
    "nsg" = true
    "prefix" = "10.248.0.0/28"
    ...
  },
  # you have only one subnet as the input, but if you had more than one the map will contain it 
  "other_subnet" = {
  ... 
  }
}
```

Essentially, we want to map the `name` of each subnet to the subnet itself. The reason why we need this is, as I stated above, `for_each` accepts only sets of strings. The value for this `toset([for s in var.subnets: s.name])` is a set of subnet names, so `set("inside")`, meaning that `for_each` will loop through the name of the subnets and create an `azurerm_subnet` for each subnet name. Obviously we need more information about the subnet, not only its name. We can get all the information we need from the `subnet_map`. This is because we can get an object out of it if we provide the name of the subnet. This is exactly what this statement does: `local.subnet_map[each.value].prefix`

Comment: Appreciate the input. Gave it a try but received the following error for each element in the subnet list:  "Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string)"

Comment: I see it. I removed the attribute 'name' from each.value.name as it isn't needed since the set only contains the names. So it looks like it works

Comment: Could you elaborate on  subnet_map = { for s in var.subnets: s.name=> s } ?

Comment: Updated my answer with more information.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! Does that then follow to the network security groups as well? I'm struggling with extending what you've outlined here into pulling out the rules that reside within the same dataset.

Comment: You can get the security group rules using `local.subnet_map[each.value].security_group_rules`.  Since this is a list, you can index it: `local.subnet_map[each.value].security_group_rules[0].name ` - this will give you `AllowAllInbound`